# Formatação de String em um TextView a partir de dados de um Array no Parse

Tags: ios, objective-c

Estou fazendo um aplicativo para cadastro de alunos de uma escola usando TabBar, e uma das Tabs é a Tab de consulta.

Nesta tab, tenho um campo de busca, onde o usuário deve digitar o nome do aluno e o mesmo aparecerá em um TextView, após clicado no botão buscar.

Estou utilizando o servidor do Parse, que me fornece métodos de "Query" para os dados, inclusive já me fornece um Array onde os objetos são armazenados.

O meu método de busca, a Action do botão buscar, está da seguinte forma:

```
 - (IBAction)buscarAlunos:(id)sender {

 // Busca
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Aluno"];

 // Busca com as Keys abaixo    
    [query selectKeys:@[@"firstName",@"lastName",@"telephone,classDate"]];

 // Método fornecido pelo Parse
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

     // Método para efetuar a busca no Array objects com os dados do campo
        [query whereKey:self.buscarTextField.text containsAllObjectsInArray:objects];

    // Array para guardar os itens da busca  
        NSMutableArray* busca = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

       [busca addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[objects componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"]]];

   // Exibir no textView
       self.textViewResgate.text = [busca componentsJoinedByString:@"\n"];
    }];
}
```

O problema que ocorre é que o meu `textView` sempre exibe os resultados com as chaves e alguns códigos. Acredito não estar formatando da forma correta.

O resultado aparece assim:

```
<Aluno: FA49wkjYMA:(null)>{
firstName=Jose
lastName=da Silva
}
```

Teria como eu tirar essas chaves e códigos? Não sei se `stringWithFormat` é a melhor forma de exibir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu não sei exatamente como funciona esse metodo do Parse (na verdade nunca usei o Parse), mas olhando o seu código, como você disse, também acho que é uma questão de formatação. O que vou sugerir não foi testado ok? Acredito que isso possa funcionar do jeito que você quer, vamos lá!

```
- (IBAction)buscarAlunos:(id)sender {

 // Busca
    PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Aluno"];

 // Busca com as Keys abaixo    
    [query selectKeys:@[@"firstName",@"lastName",@"telephone,classDate"]];

 // Método fornecido pelo Parse
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

     // Método para efetuar a busca no Array objects com os dados do campo
        [query whereKey:self.buscarTextField.text containsAllObjectsInArray:objects];

   // Exibir no textView (coloquei dentro de um gdc direcionando para a main thread, por que como esse bloco esta em background)
      dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

        for(NSDictionary *object in objects)
          self.textViewResgate.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@", object[@"firstName"], object[@"lastName"]];

      });

    }];
}
```

Perceba que eu usei a notação de colchetes (`[]`) para obter os valores das propriedades `firstName` e `lastName`, você também pode usar o método `objectForKey:` que faz a mesma coisa.

Bom espero ter ajudado, boa sorte!

Comment: Ok, minha resposta ta meio "coxa" por que esqueci que esse é um bloco de repetição, então você pode usar um NSMutableString para dar o "append" dos nomes antes de atribui-los ao seu campo de texto. Se precisar de uma ajuda nisso é só pedir ;)

Comment: Legal que bom que ajudou. No caso do mutable string, você pode instanciar uma variavel do tipo NSMutableString e usar o método de instancia "appendFormat" no bloco de repetição para varrer todos os itens dentro de "objects". Depois é só atribuir-la ao text do seu text view.

Comment: Uma coisa que está acontecendo agora, é que sempre quando clico no campo busca ele me retorna o último cadastrado, e nunca o que eu digitei no campo. Teria alguma relação com o dispatch, ou o laço? Vou tentar fazer o appendFormat.

Comment: Faz sentido, por que no snippet que te mandei, ele sempre vai manter o nome e sobrenome do ultimo registro (falha minha), quando você fazer com `appendFormat`, você vai ter uma string com todos nomes e sobrenomes mesclados.

Comment: hmm legal. Eu tentei fazer o appendFormat, mas realmente não estou conseguindo. Tentei algo do tipo: NSMutableString* buscaAlunos = [[NSMutableString alloc] init]; e depois self.textViewResgate.text = [buscaAlunos appendFormat:@"firstName"]; Acho que a sintaxe para escrever está me confundindo. O tópico deixa voce editar a sua resposta acima lá no código? Acho que vou conseguir visualizar melhor. Mais uma vez obrigado Jan.

Comment: Acho que eu consegui. O que ocorreu foi o seguinte, o método do Parse que eu estava utilizando não estava fazendo a Query da forma correta. Eu escolhei uma das Keys para digitar no campo busca, alando que o mesmo seja igual ao digitado. Ficando assim: [query whereKey:@"firstName" equalTo:self.buscarTextField.text];Depois fiz o que você falou dentro do findobjectsinBackgroundWithBlock e do dispatch. NSMutableString* buscaAlunos = [[NSMutableString alloc] init]; e self.textViewResgate.text = [buscaAlunos stringByAppendingFormat:@"Nome: %@ Sobrenome: %@",object[@"firstName"],object[@"lastName"]];

Comment: Muito Obrigado Jan. Precisando também, só falar.

Answer (score 0):

Você não precisa ficar fazendo um loop pelos elementos dos arrays. Todo `NSArray` possui o método `componentsJoinedByString`, onde você passa um caracter separador, digamos, uma vírgula, e ele monta a string de descrição.

```
NSArray *words = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Olá", @"Stackoverflow", @"em", @"pt-BR", nil];
NSLog(@"%@",[word componentsJoinedByString:@" "]);
```

Por exemplo, o resultado das duas linhas acima, será "Olá Stackoverflow em pt-BR".